# Odoo 10 : How to create many2many field?

Tags: relational-database, odoo

Is there any explanation with example of many2many fields? What is the difference between relational tables and models ??

Comment: Have you checked the docs? what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have two table teacher and student...
student has multiple teacher and teacher also has multiple students so here we can not apply many2one and many2one relationship so we need to add many2many relationship on this two tables...

suppose in odoo we have two model 'student.student' and 'teacher.teacher' so we can apply many2many relationship like this in student.student model

```
techer_ids = fields.Many2many('teacher.teacher', 'student_teacher_rel', string='Teachers')
```

how it works,
it will create different table in database with name **student_teacher_rel** .
this table has two column teacher_id and student_id both are foreign key of student table and teacher table...
so we can easily manage relationship between them...